# UIWebView Size changes?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Basically, I have two buttons that can link to one page which contains a UIWebView. The first button is via a Tab Bar Controller, so naturally there is a Tab Bar down the bottom, that is fine. However, the second button is on a page that is connected to a navigation controller, so when opening the UIWebView page from THIS button, a navigation bar appears. This seems to throw off the sizing of the UIWebView as it HASN'T been sized to cater for the navigation bar.

I have tried hiding the Navigation Bar on the UIWebView page (which would work) but any page I visit AFTER I have visited that UIWebView page seems to have its Navigation Bar hidden too.

See the two images below for further clarification.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ4yG.png  <- [When opening the page from the tab bar]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM90H.png  <- [When opening the page from the Nav bar page]

My questions are: How can I change it so the UIWebView changes position according to whether there is a Navigation bar there or not.
**or**
How can I hide the navigation bar on JUST that UIWebView page? Without it making it hide on all other pages.

Thanks heaps

Comment: Page contains UIWebView is ViewController class??

Comment: maybe you programming with auto LayOut active, is possible to generate this issue

Comment: @Erik I have made a separate class for this Webpage, I have called it 'TransportWebView'

Comment: @Jhon when I select the view controller, and press 'Show File Inspector' the 'Use AutoLayout' check box is UNCHECKED.

Comment: I had same problem on my UIWebView, and it happen when i pass from iOS6.x app to iOS7, solved only to adjust manually in the storyboard. try to delete the UIWebView from a storyboard, run app and redo manually your webview

Comment: Problem is @Jhon, I need the UIWebView to suit two different sizes, one size with the Navigation bar there, and the other size without the Nav bar. I would like to be able to hide the Navigation Bar completely, but that seems to hide the navigation bar on other pages, which is not good. If I could hide it on JUST that one page ONLY, that would be great.

Comment: @n00bAppDev no sorry i can't understand, want you hide NavBar in the ViewController at the top, or from your webview your NavBar named TRANSlink? can you post a Screen of your StoryBoard?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have mentioned, the 'TRANSlink' is part of the WebView, I did not create that. The thing that I want to change is, if you look at the second link I attached, there is a blank space between the Nav bar and the top of the WebView, I want to get rid of this, or even better, somehow get the Toolbar back from where ever it went. (It just disappears when I access the WebView from the second button)
I will attach a picture of the relevant story board @Jhon

Comment: @Jhon Here is my storyboard (part of it) http://i.stack.imgur.com/dHM8x.png <- [The button called "Ryges South Bank Brisbane" is linked to the WebView page]

Comment: so you have two differnt UiView in the storyboard with the same UIWebVie right? but with no apparent explanationn in one of this you see a blank bar at the top of your webview. right?

Comment: Umm Correct. For explanation purposes lets call the page with the UIWebView (and the only page with a web view) Transport.
The Transport page can bee accessed from the Tab Bar, AND it can be accessed through the 'Dinner Info Web View' page (See storyboard

When you access Transport through the tab bar, you DO NOT get a Navigation Bar, and since I have manually sized the UIWebview to cater for NO Nav Bar, that is why it looks fine. When you access Transport from 'Dinner Info' page a Nav Bar appears, which then creates a gap at the top of the Web View, and hides my Toolbar. 

I want to fix this

Comment: @Jhon (Just incase you didn't get the notification)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding the navbar, You can extend the webview's frame  such that it hides the navbar beneath it.

Comment: I have a Tool bar that I want to display as well. Plus, this needs to be Uploaded to the App Store and I am not sure if that 'Get around' option would be allowed?

Comment: simply add this on yout UIWebview page. navigationbar.hidden=YES;